# How to set HDFS directory times for unit testing

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to unit test a Java program that uses Hadoop's HDFS programmatic interface. I need to create directories and set their times to make sure that my program will "clean up" the directories at the right times. However, FileSystem.setTimes does not seem to work for directories, only for files. Is there any way I can set up HDFS directories access/modification times programmatically? I'm using Hadoop 0.20.204.0.

Thanks!

Frank

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is indeed HDFS bug, which marked as resolved recently. Perhaps you need to try never version or snapshot if this is critical for you.

[HDFS-2436](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2436)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to unit test Hadoop or your program? If latter then the proper way to do it is to abstract any infrastructure dependencies, such as HDFS and use stub/mock in your tests.

Comment: Maxim - if I have access to the real HDFS, why stub/mock?

Comment: @Frank Stub/mocking will allow you to test your code with out needing to actually manipulate the HDFS. When doing unit testing, you need to remove any dependency your code has, through stub/mocking. If you require the HDFS, technically that's integration testing. Why try to change the HDFS when you can fake the times? What if the time is in the future? hehe

Comment: OK, then I guess what I want to do is integration testing.

Comment: Sounds like integration testing. But then you don't manipulate infrastructural dependencies behavior - if HDFS doesn't allow you to change time on directories, unless it's a bug, then this is it's behavior which you should embrace.